# How to click on value in popup form in Python with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am having a trouble with a popup form in python using selenium. I would like to click into the select tag with option inside, but I always get error:

```
Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="EmaratechSG_Patterns_wt4_block_wtMainContent_wt9_wtServiceslist"]"}
  (Session info: chrome=123.0.6312.59); For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors#no-such-element-exception      
Stacktrace:
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00714CC3+225091]
        (No symbol) [0x00644E11]
        (No symbol) [0x004E9A7A]
        (No symbol) [0x0052175B]
        (No symbol) [0x0052188B]
        (No symbol) [0x00519391]
        (No symbol) [0x0053F5A4]
        (No symbol) [0x0051930E]
        (No symbol) [0x0053F7F4]
        (No symbol) [0x00555CB0]
        (No symbol) [0x0053F2F6]
        (No symbol) [0x005179B9]
        sqlite3_dbdata_init [0x00B9106A+4094762]
        sqlite3_dbdata_init [0x00B8B968+4072488]
        sqlite3_dbdata_init [0x0088C9C9+930953]
        (No symbol) [0x006507E4]
        (No symbol) [0x0064AD08]
        (No symbol) [0x0064AE31]
        (No symbol) [0x0063CAA0]
        BaseThreadInitThunk [0x7790FCC9+25]
        RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77B77C5E+286]
        RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77B77C2E+238]
```

This is my code:

```
    def find_element_and_center(driver: webdriver.Chrome, element:
                            webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement,
                            input_condition=EC.presence_of_element_located):
        input_condition = input_condition(element)
        element = WebDriverWait(driver, SHORT_WAIT).until(input_condition)
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView({block:'center'})", element)
        return element
    def click_element(driver: webdriver.Chrome,
                  element: webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement) -> None:
        e = find_element_and_center(driver, element)
        e.click()

    SHORT_WAIT = 30
    THIRD_PAGE_ELEMENT['application_form'] = 'WebForm1'
    THIRD_PAGE_ELEMENT['application_caret_drop_down'] = 'EmaratechSG_Patterns_wt4_block_wtMainContent_wt9_wtServiceslist'
    application_form = WebDriverWait(driver, SHORT_WAIT).\
            until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(id_tuple_generator(THIRD_PAGE_ELEMENT['application_form'])))
    print('Third page opened')

    time.sleep(5)
        
    application_type = application_form.find_element(By.ID, THIRD_PAGE_ELEMENT['application_caret_drop_down'])
```

The error always occur in application_type
and this is the value that I want to get:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/otNhS.png)

Comment: Screenshots of the UI are great, screenshots of code or HTML are not. Please read why [a screenshot of code/HTML is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the code/HTML as text and properly format it instead.

Comment: Please read [ask], especially the part about [mcve] (MCVE). Take the code you are using, reduce it to an MCVE, and then post that code, properly formatted. Can you link the page? If not, we can't really help you. You'll have to see if the SELECT is inside an IFRAME or shadow-root or the like.

Comment: @JeffC Sorry, I'm just a beginner, and the page is: https://smart.gdrfad.gov.ae/, but you have to login to this page

Comment: You still haven't fixed the issues I mentioned. A link to the site that requires a login isn't really helpful. You're going to need to supply the relevant HTML as text, which I already mentioned.